# A sintaxe que o professor mostra não fica correta no VIsualg

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, visualg

> Toda vez que eu coloco esse codigo no visualg dá erro... Tentei até "traduzir" com um guia de comandos, mas n deu certo kkk...
> Sou de Analise e desenvolvimento de sistemas na Uninassau.

```
PROGRAMA TabuadaMultiplicacao;
INÍCIO

    VARIÁVEL
        intFator, intProduto, intNumero: INTEIRO;
    
LIMPAR_TELA ( ) ;
ESCREVER (“Digite o número desejado: “);
LER (intNumero);

REPITA PARA intFator DE 11 ATÉ 20
    ESCREVER (TEXTO (intNumero) + “X” + INT_PARA_TEXTO (intFator) + “=” +INT_PARA_TEXTO (intNumero * intFator);
FIM
```

Comment: Qual(is) erro(s) , ajude também...

Comment: simplesmente não aparece descrição do erro.. só dá sintaxe incorreta

Comment: @Motta simplesmente não aparece descrição do erro.. só dá sintaxe incorreta

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

não sei qual versão do Visualg está usando, fiz o teste com a versão 3.0.7.0, inicialmente notei que a palavra "VARIÁVEL" está acentuada e pode ser um erro, outros pontos que retornaram erro quando testei foram os parênteses que estavam num formato diferente do aceito por essa versão.
As funções LIMPAR_TELA, ESCREVER, LER, TEXTO e INT_PARA_TEXTO também não existem. O laço de repetição também estava incorreto nessa versão, fiz as alterações para as correspondentes corretas.

Com esses ajustes consegui rodar o código aqui.

```
Algoritmo "TabuadaMultiplicacao"

Var
   intFator: INTEIRO,
   intProduto: INTEIRO,
   intNumero: INTEIRO

inicio
   LIMPATELA;
   ESCREVAL ("Digite o numero desejado: ")
   LEIA (intNumero)

   PARA intFator DE 11 ATÉ 20 faca
   ESCREVAL (Numpcarac(intNumero)+ "X"+ Numpcarac(intFator)+ "=" +Numpcarac(intNumero * intFator))
   FIMPARA
Fimalgoritmo
```

[Aqui](https://manual.visualg3.com.br/doku.php?id=manual#:%7E:text=O%20comando%20escreva%20escreve%20no,lista%2Dde%2Dexpress%C3%B5es%3E.) tem um manual que pode te ajudar também.

Comment: Nossa mano, muito obrigado! A sintaxe que passaram estava realmente errada...